# What does `>f..tp......` when using rsync?

Tags: rsync

When using `rsync`,  it prints

```
>f..tp......  /foo/bar
```

What does the `>f..tp......` mean?

Comment: For less specific questions, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4493525/what-does-f-mean-in-rsync-logs is also helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the `rsync(1)` man page:

> A  `>`  means that a file is being transferred to the local
>                        host (received).

...

> `f` for a file

...

> A `t` means the modification time is different

...

> A  `p`  means  the  permissions are different